# Return an array of all directories inside a directory without parent directories in php

Tags: php, directory, subdirectory, scandir

So basically: I want to get an array of all directories (and only directories/folders, no files) inside a given directory. It should not include sub directories and no parent directories.

A similar code for files only way easy to do:

```
$files = array_filter(scandir('/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts/'), function($item) {
    return !is_dir('/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts/' . $item);
    });
```

But removing the negation in:

```
return !is_dir('/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts/' . $item);
```

does keep the parent directories in the array.

Comment: This should be a separate function or method, that way you don't have to repeat the path. See: [Don't repeat yourself.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) To remove the parent directory you can add an extra condition to the `array_filter()` callback function.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this.

Comment: I used that to exclude parent directories($dirsx is the array with the parent directories included, created with the beforementioned function):


  
  $dirs = array_values(array_diff($dirsx, array('..', '.')));